# unable to link geometry shader properly

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to create a simple passthrough "Geometry Shader" but for some reason its not linking. Debug info says its compiling fine.I don't know what I am doing wrong in this one? It is not the drivers or OS as I have linked and used geometry shader before, and they worked fine.

Vertex Shader code:

```
#version 450

in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 MVP;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
    color = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader code:

```
#version 450

in vec4 fColor;
out vec4 fcolor;

void main() {
    fcolor = fColor;
}
```

Geometry Shader Code:

```
#version 450

layout(lines) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = color;
    for(int i = 0; i <= gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Debug output:

> In Compile Shader from file:  ../Curve.vert compile result::  1 Shader
> compile and attach success:  In Compile Shader from file:
> ../Curve.geom compile result::  1 Shader compile and attach success:
> In Compile Shader from file:  ../Curve.frag compile result::  1 Shader
> compile and attach success:  Linking.. , Program handle found:  1 GL
> Renderer         : GeForce GTX 1660 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 GL Vendor           :
> NVIDIA Corporation GL Version          : 4.6.0 NVIDIA 461.40 GL
> Version No.      : 4.6 GLSL Version        : 4.60 NVIDIA
> --------------- Debug message (131216): Program/shader state info: GLSL program 1 failed to link Source: API Type: Other Severity: low
>
> Curve shader program not linked Curve shader program not validated Use
> unsuccessful, returning? m_linked status:  false Program handle:  1
> Curve shader program handle:  1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Geometry Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader) transforms [Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) and is executed for each primitive. Therefore, the input of the Geometry Shader is an array the size of the vertex number of the primitives. e.g.:

```c
in vec4 color[];
```

You have to emit a vertex for each vertex of the output primitive.